# Как сделать автоматическую прокрутку к якорю?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать автоматическую прокрутку к якорю?
К примеру нужно прокрутить до блока.
Прошу помощь в нахождение решения!
Библиотека jquery 1.8.1
<footer>Это первое, что вы читаете</footer>

Comment: Всем спасибо, сам нашел решение
var pos = $("footer").position();
 $("body,html").animate({ 
 scrollTop: pos.top 
 }, 800);

Comment: поразительно, но ведь это решение можно было найти ДО создания вопроса

Comment: ScrollInto View может поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам надо анимированный скролл или моментальное перемещение?
второй вариант это 
    <a name="anchor">перейти</a>
    <a href="#anchor">вот и перешел</a>

на jquery , к вашему примеру можно
    $(window).scrollTop($('footer').offset().top);